# CPU cores have a temperature near 80 °C and then the fan starts to work. Is it too late?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I have MBP 13, 2015.

When I watch some videos CPU Core 1 and 2 have a temperature near 70-80 °C. At this time the fan starts to work with some 1300 rpm.

Is it a bad temperature in the meaning of long term condition for the cores' life?

Should I configure my fan to increase the rpm at lower temperatures?

Comment: Your computer is designed to shut itself off before physical damage occurs.

Comment: @Harv thx for your comment. I have post my comment under the jkseogaard's answer. Please post your thoughts there to avoid duplication. :) I thought the less temperature - the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a "bad" temperature. If your MBP 13" 2015 model is configured with the default CPU, it is specced to work at up to 105° C. So running at 70 or 80 degrees is no problem at all.

In general you should never change the configuration of your fans away from the defaults supplied by Apple.

Comment: Thx for you response!  I thought  less temperature mean more life expectation for hardware components.

Comment: If we have 2 ways. 1 one: fan is always on, the temperature is always low and the fan will be broken sooner than the default way. 2 one: default fan configuration, more ° C, less lifetime for hardware components, than in the first way. Right or wrong? :)

Comment: In practice you're wrong. Lower temperature does not always equal higher life expectancy - for example if you run it at -50 degrees, you're likely to harm the hardware. So there's a certain temperature range that is optimal - and Apple ofcourse takes this into account when designing the thermal characteristics of the MBP. Intel specifies that if you keep the CPU below 105 degrees, you're "good" - and they will uphold their warranties etc. And yes, in general for electronics it is better to run at 40 degrees than 80 degrees - that can be noticeable with cheaper capacitors - but not CPUs

Comment: Often it is less harmful to run the system at a constant temperature rather than have huge temperature variance - even though the constant temperature is higher than the mean temperature of the system with the varying temperature.... but in practice a laptop will have several other failing components before the CPU breaks. CPUs generally last very long, so there's not really an idea in being super conscious about not having a high CPU-load if that takes your life time from 20 years to 20.5 years.